# How to make safe sushi?

Tags: food-safety, sushi

I really want to make sushi (and sashimi). However, I'm concerned about the health risks of eating raw fish.

I made a research and I found this:

> EU
>   regulations forbid the use of fresh raw fish. It must be frozen at
>   temperatures below −20 °C (−4 °F) in all parts of the product for no
>   less than 24 hours.[66] As such, a number of fishing boats, suppliers
>   and end users "super-freeze" fish for sushi to temperatures as low as
>   −60 °C.[67] As well as parasite destruction, super-freezing also
>   prevents oxidation of the blood in tuna flesh, thus preventing the
>   discoloration that happens at temperatures above −20 °C.[68]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi.

So I wonder if it's safe if I freeze the raw fish in my refrigerator's freezer for a day or two? Any advice on making safe sushi?

Comment: In the US we have sushi grade fish that has been frozen.   Does not really help you.

Comment: Are you wanting to make it with fish you caught yourself? Is there a reason you want to freeze it yourself rather than buying fish that's ready to use as sushi from your fish supplier?